# control hardware back button

Tags: javascript, android

In my application, I want to control the hardware back button. That means if in my app there are four or five activity. Now suppose I move from one activity to another,

like this "start 1->2->3->4->2->4->1 end" Now in my case when I press the hardware back button it reaches 1st page in similar manner,

"end 1<-2<-3<-4<-2<-4<-1 start"

so my question is that what should I do so that when I press the hardware back button

on 1st page exit
on 2nd page reach 1st page (pressed back button again) exit.

etc...

on 4th page reach 3rd (back button) 2nd (back) 1st (back) exit.

Comment: override method onbackButtonPressed() of every activity and do what ever you want to do, ideally android removed the top activity from stack so what ever you saying will be achieved by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method `onBackPressed()` . You can override that method in your activity to achieve this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent go=new Intent(this.class,your_desired_activity.class);
    startActivity(go);
    super.onBackPressed();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

launch actvity withActivity flag clear top  so that every activity on top of stack will be get cleared .

so in case if you launch your activity 2 with clear top   after  this sequence start ->1<-2<-3<-4<- **2**

your stack will be start->1->2

similary if you lauch your activity 1  with clear top flag after this sequence
start 1->2->3->4->2->4-  **1**

your stack will be  start->1

you can read more about back stack here
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html